# Is there a reason why pubkey in `Reward` struct is `String` instead of `&[u8]` or `Pubkey`

Tags: geyser, solana-sdk, rewards

In most places `pubkey` is represented by `&[u8]` or `Pubkey` is there any particular reason why [`Reward`](https://docs.rs/solana-transaction-status/1.14.5/solana_transaction_status/struct.Reward.html) struct inside [`ReplicaBlockInfo`](https://docs.rs/solana-geyser-plugin-interface/1.14.5/solana_geyser_plugin_interface/geyser_plugin_interface/struct.ReplicaBlockInfo.html) use this "fronted/json friendly" representation? Similar question could be asked about `blockhash` field.

Copied structures:

```
pub struct ReplicaBlockInfo<'a> {
    pub slot: u64,
    pub blockhash: &'a str,
    pub rewards: &'a [Reward],
    pub block_time: Option<UnixTimestamp>,
    pub block_height: Option<u64>,
}

pub struct Reward {
    pub pubkey: String,
    pub lamports: i64,
    pub post_balance: u64,
    pub reward_type: Option<RewardType>,
    pub commission: Option<u8>,
}
```

Can I safely translate

- in Reward struct:   `pubkey: String` -> `pubkey: Pubkey`
- in ReplicaBlockInfo `hash: &'a str` -> `hash: Hash` ([`Hash`](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/hash/struct.Hash.html))

To store this information more effectively inside database (use BYTEA instead of TEXT).

Answer (score 2):

The question of "why" is probably better suited for a GitHub issue, since it does seem strange.  Otherwise, yes you can assume that they are both base-58 encoded byte arrays.